# Django cookies place double quotes around email address

Tags: django, email, cookies, double-quotes

On my login script it creates a cookie for the user logging in of their email address and password. Problem I am having is when the email address is set it puts the entire email address between double quotes. How would I get it to not?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     post = request.POST
     email = post.get('email', None)
     response.set_cookie('emailaddress', email, max_age=expire_v)
```

Comment: WHAT? You're storing the user's password in a cookie? Why would you do that?

Comment: It's a secure cookie and the password is encrypted when stored.

Comment: But that didn't answer the question. Why on earth would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: And if you want us to answer your actual question, you'll need to show the code you're using to create the cookie.

Comment: If a user wants to be able to close their browser and than come back and be able to go straight into the site I believe storing their password within a salt is fine. Each users password is encrypted and a random salt is created for each user.

Comment: @Bobby **NEVER store a password in a cookie**, even when it is encrypted and salted, as when a cookie gets stolen, it gives unrevokable access to an account. Instead you want to store a [Session Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID) or something similar in your cookie.

Comment: @Bobby Indeed, why not just use the full Django session framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try strip method

```
email.strip('"')
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem, as it seems to happen after creating the cookie and not before.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but by placing it within `email = urllib.quote_plus(email)` solves my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution for this issue is to directly work with a ***SimpleCookie*** object and attach it to your *response*

```
>>> from Cookie import SimpleCookie
>>> mycookie = SimpleCookie()
>>> mycookie['emailaddress'] = 'josuebrunel@gmail.com'
>>> mycookie['emailaddress']['expires'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> print(mycookie)
Set-Cookie: emailaddress="josuebrunel@gmail.com"; expires=2015-11-25 22:20:16
>>> response.cookies = mycookies
```

I had the same issue, and i fixed by using **SimpleCookie**

Comment: This solution is not works. Double qoutes are also added to email.

Comment: Did you check the js_output of the cookie ? I mean 

   >>> mycookie.js_output()

You will notice that the quotes are escaped

Comment: Nope. I attached cookies to my HttpResponse and tested with curl. Returned email was surrounded with double quotes.

Comment: Excuse me, but that doesn't mean that a browser won't be able to recognize the cookie. 
That was my issue, and this worked for me. 
May be i would be able to help you better if i knew what your issue was ?

Comment: Browser recognizes such cookie and I can see it via browser settings or via javascript. But Django automatically surrounds every cookie with '@' sign in double quotes. The solution for me was to urlencode these cookies. The initial problem was to get rid of double quotes in cookie. Solution with SimpleCookie doesn't make it.