# double quotes is getting appended while setting oauth2 cookie

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, setcookie

i am implementing oauth2 with django rest framework in my web app.when i am trying to set cookie:

```
result.set_cookie("Authorization", "Bearer "+data['access_token'])
```

django is appending a double quotes in start and end, lets example:

```
"Bearer ISQkqzBsY8rFLW91Uurxqbit5ZQRoB"
```

i had tried these solution given as answer in a previous question:
[Django cookies place double quotes around email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992603/django-cookies-place-double-quotes-around-email-address), but no success.

here is a token in django developer which they have closed as invalid, but i'm not getting why? https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19641

thanks in advance. Any help will be greatly appreciated.